# Fill input tag of an html in python

Tags: web-scraping

So I have tried web scraping a website and it has a field where you can write ( a navigation bar of some sort )
Whenever I am writing something there it creates a dropdown of things related to what I wrote ( things that contain what I wrote )
What I'm trying to do is essentially use requests.post from requests library in python in order to fill a value inside it, afterwards, I want it to grab whatever the dropdown showed.

I've had a few problems while doing it:

1. The dropdown disappears whenever you click somewhere else on the website so it does create temporary HTML tags of the list temporarily.
2. I couldn't find a way to actually post something inside the navigation bar.

A great example I've found on the web is inside FUTWIZ which does exactly what I described above, Whenever I try with F12 I see it creates some HTML description, is there a way to grab the HTML After the value is put inside the actual navigation bar?

[image]

### EDIT

---

This is the code I've tried:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urls = "https://www.futwiz.com/en/"

requst = requests.get(urls)
bs4Out = BeautifulSoup(requst.text, "html.parser")
poster = requests.post(urls, data={"form-control": "Messi"})
print(poster.text)
```

Now, I know the data in requests.post only puts it as a query but I can't really figure out how to fill the header
This is the link to FUTWIZ, it has the navigation bar which is the thing I'm trying to work with?
https://www.futwiz.com/en/

Comment: Hello, can we have the website link please ?

Comment: Try finding what requests are being made when you enter text in the box using the browser developer tools, then see if you can make those requests directly.

Comment: Please read [ask] and show us what you've tried in a [mre].

Comment: @Baduker, I edited the answer, you can see it below, thanks for you help